# cin.get() in while loop not getting clear idea

Tags: c++

in loop there is a cout statement which prints the character which provide from keyboard but inside loop it is not showing it even keep on typing keys from keyboard but when we press enter it shows all of them all together 
why there is cin.get() outside loop and how does the cin.get() inside the loop behave actually

kindly reply
thankx

Comment: `char c; cin.get(c); while (c != '\n') { cout << c; cin.get(c); }` or something close to that.  The loop termination condition needs work - if you get EOF before newline, it probably gets very unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the operating system does not send the key strokes to your program until you hit return at the end of the line.  Until then, you can edit the line with backspace or delete, and possibly other characters.

If you want to read one character at a time as typed, then you have to adjust the I/O mode of your terminal (on Unix and its derivatives) to 'raw' mode.  This can be done with the curses library, though that's overkill (but convenient) if you are not going to use its display facilities.